# collision taking after image also?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm creating a car parking game for collision detection.

My problem is its checking the collision after the image has updated.

[image: it's taking collision there I want to take at starting]

[image: check this one also]

My Phaser code:

```
var app = angular.module('myapp',[]);
app.controller('mycontrol',function($scope){
var game = new Phaser.Game(1100, 590, Phaser.AUTO, 'cargame');
var mainState = { 
 preload:function(){
     game.load.image('wood','images/wood1.png'); 
    game.load.image('car', 'images/maincar.png');

},

create:function(){


    game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);
    this.car =this.game.add.sprite(game.world.centerX,game.world.centerY,'car');
   //this.car.body.collide = true;
    this.car.anchor.setTo(0.5,0.5);
     //this.wood1.anchor.setTo(0.5,0.5);

    game.physics.arcade.enable(this.car);                     
    this.car.body.allowRotation = true; 
     platforms = game.add.group();
     platforms.enableBody = true;

       var ground = platforms.create(200,300, 'wood');
    ground.body.immovable = true;
},                                                              

update:function(){



            if(game.input.keyboard.isDown(Phaser.Keyboard.LEFT)){
                this.car.body.angularVelocity = -200;
            }
            else if(game.input.keyboard.isDown(Phaser.Keyboard.RIGHT)){
                this.car.body.angularVelocity = 200;
            }
            else if(game.input.keyboard.isDown(Phaser.Keyboard.UP)){
               this.car.body.velocity.copyFrom(game.physics.arcade.velocityFromAngle(this.car.angle, 150));
            }
            else if(game.input.keyboard.isDown(Phaser.Keyboard.DOWN)){
               this.car.body.velocity.copyFrom(game.physics.arcade.velocityFromAngle(this.car.angle, -150));
            }
            else{
                this.car.body.angularVelocity =0;  
                 this.car.body.velocity.x =0;
                this.car.body.velocity.y = 0;
            }
            game.physics.arcade.collide(this.car, platforms);




},

};




$scope.car1 = function(){
    game.state.add('main', mainState);  
game.state.start('main'); 

};
});
```

and html

```
<html>
<head>
<script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="controller2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="phaser.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="mycontrol">
<div id="cargame" ng-click="car1()">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

From phaser docs (Physics.Arcade, [collide method](http://phaser.io/docs/2.4.4/Phaser.Physics.Arcade.html#collide)):

> An optional processCallback can be provided. If given this function
>   will be called when two sprites are found to be colliding. It is
>   called before any separation takes place, giving you the chance to
>   perform additional checks. If the function returns true then the
>   collision and separation is carried out

So, you can do something like this:

```
game.physics.arcade.collide(this.car, platforms, myCallBack);
```

And then, you define 'myCallBack' funtion, where you can do whatever you want with the objects in collision.

Comment: here my question is it's taking collision top and bottom middle of the image..right side taking so much which  I showed in screen shots...how to overcome this problem...if you don't mind can you give any example code for two objects..

Comment: ok, then I didn't understand your problem... can you upload somewhere your code(jsfiddle or similar), so I can see the problem?

Comment: k see the screen shots which i have posted ...in first one collision is taking till the end of red line so i want to cancel collision redline starting itself..